# opencv not capturing all frames

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect the position of the ball throughout a video. In the beginning, I crop the video because my original clip has some random things at the top. I don't know why but the program doesn't capture all the frames - it sort of stops after the first frame. I tried it on another computer and it works. I have no idea what's wrong.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video-4.mp4')

while(1):
    success, frame = cap.read()
    # Take each frame
    if success:
        crop_img = frame[100:3000, 100:3000].copy()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1.5, minDist=505,param1=75, param2=30, minRadius=8, maxRadius=10)
        # ensure at least some circles were found
        if circles is not None:
            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                print(x,y,r)
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
                # corresponding to the center of the circle
                cv2.circle(crop_img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x - 5, y - 5),
                            (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        cv2.namedWindow("hi", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('hi', crop_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        break
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: if you know that it is red try thresholding red color and use minEnclosingCircle function to choose the circle, or fitEllipse or a proprietary RANSAC circle detection.

Comment: You mean it fails at reading frames after that? Is your issue even related to any processing you want to apply to the frames?

Comment: @couka well probably not but why doesn't my code read all the frames?

Comment: Please check if just reading is the issue and update the question accordingly

Comment: @couka my bad..

Comment: No worries, refining the question is part of the process when figuring out what's wrong. If reading fails after some frame, I'd suspect a video format issue. Try converting the file to a different format.

Comment: @couka I tried with a few different formats they all don’t work.... I think it’s something with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using `y` without initialising it.
- You are using `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` as though it is the width but it isn't. It is just a *"define"* to tell an **OpenCV** function what to return.
- You are indexing `frame` by width first, when you should use height as the first index.

Comment: yes! I realized that and I have edited the code in post, but it still, only captures sort of the first two frames.... I don't know why that happens

Comment: You set `x` and `y` above the main loop like they are constants, but you redefine them in the interior when looking for circles.

Comment: Hi there, yes I fixed it sorry about that. I tried this code on anther computer and it worked. On my computer it only runs on a few frames, not all the frames....

Comment: In order to debug it, try changing the `waitKey()` parameter to 30. Also try commenting out the entire `if circles is not None` block to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: hi there thank you so much for the suggestion. I tried a simple loop over the video without doing anything. Even just looping over frames of a video it only shows a few frames. I tried the exact same code on replit(online IDE), it worked perfectly. It might be something to do with my python set up/opencv set up